# Access registered object in Nancy Startup class

Tags: .net-core, nancy, tinyioc

I'm writing a service in Nancy and I'm using some middleware for monitoring the service:

```
    app.UseOwin(buildFunc => 
    { 
        var log = ConfigureLogger();
        buildFunc.UseMonitoringAndLogging(log, HealthCheck);
        buildFunc.UseNancy();
    });
```

The middleware is configured to use a `HealthCheck()` function defined in the `Startup` class as:

```
    public async Task<bool> HealthCheck()
    {
        return await SomeRepo.HealthCheck();
    }
```

`SomeRepo` has a `HealthCheck()` method that queries the database to confirm it is available/responding. But how to inject `SomeRepo` into the `Startup` class, or alternatively access the container to resolve `SomeRepo`?

Answer (score 0):

At this point you are still in Owin and not in the Nancy pipeline. What host are you running on ? If you are using `aspnetcore` the you can register your deps  in `RegisterServices()` method and it will handle the injection into your method. You can use `Autofac` or `StructureMap` so you can share your container with Nancy as well like [this](https://slack-files.com/T0B46TQ02-F5LBJRTGT-e2fb109ef5).

Comment: Thanks - I've moved from TinyIoC to SimpleInjector so I can register decorators. I'm registering my repo in `Startup.cs` in the SimpleInjector container. Nancy has a design principle that the container isn't directly accessible from a module. As a workaround I've saved the container to a public static property but I would like a better option.

Comment: You can pass the container to the bootstapper and the override `GetApplicationContainer()` to return your instance